# .java uses unchecked and unsafe operation

Tags: java, swing, warnings, unsafe, unchecked

here is my java code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Employee1 extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;
    JLabel l1;
    JList list;

    public Employee1() {
        super("Employee Details");
        panel = new JPanel();
        l1 = new JLabel("City : ");
        String cities[] = {"Mumbai", "Delhi", "Madras"};
        list = new JList(cities);
        panel.add(l1);
        panel.add(list);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee1 obj = new Employee1();
    }
}
```

**this code gives me warning .java uses unchecked and unsafe operation. i have exams so please help me to go through it**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of a type parameter for your JList because this is a generics error and JList supports genercis.

Change:

`JList list` to `JList<String> list`
 and `list = new JList(cities)` to `list = new JList<>(cities)`

```
public class Employee1 extends JFrame {
    private final JPanel panel;
    private final JLabel l1;
    private final JList<String> list;    // <--- first change

    public Employee1() {
        super("Employee Details");

        final String[] cities = {"Mumbai", "Delhi", "Madras"};

        panel = new JPanel();
        l1    = new JLabel("City : ");
        list  = new JList<>(cities);     // <--- second change

        panel.add(l1);
        panel.add(list);
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

See [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for information and examples on this topic

Comment: i am beginner so explain me where exactly i have to change

Comment: +1 for generic type safety, but see also `pack()` and [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).